# Im trying to figure out why my squares cant match up properly can anyone help me figure it out

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm currently stuck because the program runs perfectly fine but when I try to eat the food it doesn't work because the food is in a weird position. What I mean by weird position is that when I go over it with the snake it doesn't register.
At first, I thought it was because I was getting a decimal so I tried to put it into an int, but apparently, that did not work.
Snake game, SDL, c++

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_keycode.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Food
{
    int Height;
    int Width;
    int x_Pos;
    int y_Pos;

    void move()
    {
        int x_Pos = rand() % 400 + 40;//random pos
        int y_Pos = rand() % 400 + 40;
    }

    void draw(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
    {
        SDL_Rect r{ x_Pos, y_Pos, 20, 20 };
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 0);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &r);
    }
};

struct v2
{
    int x, y;
};

v2 operator+ (const v2& a, const v2& b)
{
    return v2{ a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y };
}

void operator+= (v2& a, const v2& b)
{
    a.x += b.x;
    a.y += b.y;
}

struct Snake
{
    int Height;
    int Width;
    v2 pos;
    v2 vel;
    int vX, vY;
    uint32_t accumulator;

    void update(uint32_t delta_time, Food& food) 
    {
        accumulator += delta_time;
        if (accumulator > 50)// update every 50 ms
        {
            accumulator = 0;
            pos.x += vel.x;
            pos.y += vel.y;

            if (pos.x == food.x_Pos && pos.y == food.y_Pos)
            {
                food.move();
            }
        }
    }

    void draw(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
    {
        SDL_Rect r{ pos.x, pos.y, 20, 20 };
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 255, 0, 0);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &r);
    }

};

bool isRunning = true;

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 700;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 700;

void setup_Window(int width, int height);
void input(SDL_Renderer* renderer);
void create_Rect(SDL_Renderer* &renderer, int x, int y, int w, int h, int colorRed, int colorGreen, int colorBlue, int colorA);


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int score = 0;
    setup_Window(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    return 0;
}
void Calc()
{
    
}

void setup_Window(int width, int height)
{
    
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Subsystems Initialised!..." << std::endl;

        //The window we'll be rendering to
        SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Snake Game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        // Setup renderer
        SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
        input(renderer);
    }
}

void create_Rect(SDL_Renderer* &renderer, int x, int y, int w, int h, int colorRed, int colorGreen, int colorBlue, int colorA)
{
    // Creat a rect at pos ( 50, 50 ) that's 50 pixels wide and 50 pixels high.
    SDL_Rect r;
    r.x = x;//615
    r.y = y;//0
    r.w = w;//25
    r.h = h;//480
  
    // x = up and down 
    // y = left and right

    // Set render color to blue ( rect will be rendered in this color )
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, colorRed, colorGreen, colorBlue, colorA);
    // Render rect
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &r);

    // Render the rect to the screen
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

}

void input(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    uint32_t current_Time = 0, previous_Time, delta_Time;
    SDL_Event event;
    int rando1 = rand() % 400 + 40;
    int rando2 = rand() % 400 + 40;
    int rando3 = rand() % 400 + 40;
    int rando4 = rand() % 400 + 40;
    Snake snake_Body = {};// stuct for Snake object
    snake_Body.pos.x = rando1;//random pos
    snake_Body.pos.y = rando2;
    Food food = {}; // stuct for food object
    food.move();
    food.x_Pos = SCREEN_WIDTH/2;//random pos
    food.y_Pos = SCREEN_HEIGHT/2;
    
    while (isRunning)
    {
        previous_Time = current_Time;
        current_Time = SDL_GetTicks();
        delta_Time = current_Time - previous_Time;

        // Set render color to black ( rect will be rendered in this color )
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        /* Clear the entire screen to our selected color. */
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        create_Rect(renderer, 670, 0, 30, 700, 0, 255, 255, 255);// right rectangle
        create_Rect(renderer, 1, 0, 30, 700, 0, 255, 255, 255);// left rectangle
        create_Rect(renderer, 30, 1, 700, 30, 0, 255, 255, 255);// top rectangle
        create_Rect(renderer, 1, 670, 700, 30, 0, 255, 255, 255);// Bottom rectangle
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
           
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                isRunning = false;
            }
            if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
            {
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_LEFT:
                    {
                        snake_Body.vel.y = 0;
                        snake_Body.vel.x = -15;
                        cout << "Crouiser1" << endl;
                        break;
                    }
                    case SDLK_UP:
                    {
                        snake_Body.vel.y = -15;
                        snake_Body.vel.x = 0;
                        cout << "Crouiser2" << endl;
                        break;
                    }
                    case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    {
                        snake_Body.vel.y = 0;
                        snake_Body.vel.x = 15;
                        cout << "Crouiser3" << endl;
                        break;
                    }
                    case SDLK_DOWN:
                    {
                        snake_Body.vel.y = 15;
                        snake_Body.vel.x = 0;
                        cout << "Crouiser4" << endl;
                        break;
                    }
                    case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    {
                        isRunning = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    default: 
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
       
        snake_Body.update(delta_Time, food);
        snake_Body.draw(renderer);
        food.draw(renderer);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        SDL_Delay(100);
       
    }

}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I tried to do that but i don't know what any of that means.

Comment: That sounds like a pretty good question for Stackoverflow: a source code example, what the debugger is showing, and what is the meaning of that!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ye, I tried to learn it but I just can't get it. And if you're not gonna try to help me then I guess ill just get someone else's help. p.s. from what I have seen with the debugger that is not something you learn in one night.

Comment: You wrote "help me" in your previous comment :-)

Comment: nice bro makes no sense arguing like a 2-year-old when the situation has already passed. smh

Answer (score 0):

The collision-check in your update-function only checks if the upper left pixel of your Snake-rectangle overlaps with the upper left pixel of your Food-Rectangle.
To solve your problem, you need to implement a proper collision-check.
This code works for me:

```
bool CollisionCheck(int x1, int y1, int w1, int h1, int x2, int y2, int w2, int h2)
{
    //x-coordinate of square 1 is positioned after x + width of square 2
    bool one = x1 > (x2 + w2);
    //x-coordinate of square 2 is positioned after x + width of square 1
    bool two = (x1 + w1) < x2;
    //y-coordinate of square 1 is positioned below y + hight of square 2
    bool three = y1 > (y2 + h2);
    //y-coordinate of square 2 is positioned below y + hight of square 1
    bool four = (y1 + h1) < y2;

    if (one || two || three || four)
    {
        //If one of the above rules apply, there is NO COLLISION
        return false;
    }

    //If none of the above rules apply, there is a collision
    return true;
}
```